# ImageMagick, creating new image file name

Tags: php, html, imagemagick

Please find the code below which creates an image with the file name "masked.gif" in a default directory.

```
$size=$_POST["size"];
$label=$_POST["label"];
$font=$_POST["font"];

 $cmd = " -background transparent -font $font -pointsize $size label:$label -stroke          black -strokewidth 2 ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"animated_water.gif[0]\" -stroke black -strokewidth 2 -gravity      center -annotate +0+0 $label \) ".
"  \( -clone 0 -tile \"animated_water.gif[1]\" -stroke black -strokewidth 2 -gravity    center -annotate +0+0 $label \) ".
"  -delete 0 -set delay 15 -loop 0 -trim +repage -layers Optimize ";
$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec("convert $cmd masked.gif 2>&1", $array);
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>";
echo "</pre>";
echo "<img src='masked.gif'>";
```

I need "images" directory to be used as default directory.  Everytime it creates new image.  I need a new file name top be created for every image generated at the end.  "masked.gif" should not be replaced by new image created after that.

I prefer sequential images file name somewhat like "image1.gif" after that "images2.gif".

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure exec() is the way to go? Why not use PHPs ImageMagick functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function for the filename an dir problem:

```
function getNewFilename($dir = 'images/')
{
    $count = 0;
    if($handle = opendir($dir))
    {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                $tmp = explode("_",$file); // get the number and extension
                $tmp2 = explode(".",$tmp[1]); //get only the number
                if($tmp2[0] > $count) $count = $tmp2[0]; //set the number to the count if it is higher thand the last recorded value
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

    return $dir."masked_".$count.".gif";    
}

exec("convert $cmd ".getNewFilename()." 2>&1", $array);
```

But this is could be very slow, if you have a huge count of files.
You should use something like this instead:

```
function getNewFilename($dir = 'images/')
{
    return $dir."masked_".time().".gif";
}
```

Here you get a unique filename and they are ordered by creation.

Comment: this question nis answered ..please close this